# Combine two if conditions

Tags: php

Im a new and just learning php. I have a data table with search boxes with this code.

```
$condition  =   '';
if(isset($_REQUEST['username']) and $_REQUEST['username']!="") {
    $condition  .=  ' AND username LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['username'].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['useremail']) and $_REQUEST['useremail']!=""){
    $condition  .=  ' AND useremail LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['useremail'].'%" ';
}
```

What I need is to search with both username AND useremail. I have attempted everything I know and spent a few hours searching for a solution but with no success.

Comment: You dont actually tell us what the problem is

Comment: Why use `LIKE`, shouldn't those be an exact match?

Comment: ALSO Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: If you add a line to print out `$condition` in a log, does it contain what you think it should?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of all the keys that are to be searched. Then, create a new array and collect all conditions. Implode them in the end with `AND` as the glue. This way, query is made correctly without needing to add 100 different *if* conditions.

Use PDO objects to avoid SQL injection attacks. In the below snippet, if you ever need to add 1 more column for search, just add it in the below `$keys` array and rest works as usual without needing any further refactoring.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$keys = ['username', 'useremail'];

$conditions = [];
$placeholders = [];

foreach($keys as $key){
    if(!empty($_REQUEST[ $key ])){
        $conditions = " $key LIKE ?";
        $placeholders[] = '%' . $_REQUEST[ $key ] . '%';
    }
}

// you need to create $mysqli object here

if(count($conditions) === 0){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select * from table');
    $stmt->execute();
    // rest of your code
}else{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select * from table where '. implode(" AND ", $conditions));
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($placeholders)), ...$placeholders);
    $stmt->execute();
    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a complicated set of IF's with equals and not equals tests all over the place, but as the list of test gets bigger the IF's get almost impossible to maintain or understand. So it might be simpler to just build and array of things to AND in the query

```
$condition  =   '';
$and = []; #init the array
if(isset($_REQUEST['username']) and $_REQUEST['username']!="") {
    $and[] = ['name' => 'username', 'value' => $_REQUEST['username'] ];
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['useremail']) and $_REQUEST['useremail']!=""){
    $and[] =  [''name' => 'useremail', 'value' => $_REQUEST['useremail'] ];
}
#now build the condition string
foreach ($and as $i => $andMe) {
    if ( $i != 0 ){
        // AND required here
        $condition .= ' AND ';
    }
    $condition .= $andMe['name'] . ' = ' . $andMe['value'];
}
```

> Also I have replaced the `LIKE` with an `=` as it seems more appropriate, I assume you dont ask people to enter something a bit like there user name and email, but in fact ask for the actual username or email

Of course that would still be susceptible to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) So a better solution would be

```
#now build the condition string
foreach ($and as $i => $andMe) {
    if ( $i != 0 ){
        // AND required here
        $condition .= ' AND ';
    }
    $condition .= $andMe['name'] . ' = ?';
}
```

And then prepare the query and use the value part to bind to the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you have leading `AND` in your query.
push condition to array then join conditions.
like that

```
$condition_array  =   [];
if(isset($_REQUEST['username']) and $_REQUEST['username']!="") {
    $condition_array[] =  'username LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['username'].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['useremail']) and $_REQUEST['useremail']!=""){
    $condition_array[] =  'useremail LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['useremail'].'%" ';
}
$condition = implode(" AND ",$condition_array);
```